# Waking up thread from signal handler

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals, signal-handling

I understand that about the only thing, a signal handler in ISO/C++11 is allowed to do is to read from or write to a lock free atomic variable or a `volatile sig_atomic_t` (I believe, POSIX is a little bit more permissive and allows to call a bunch of system functions).

I was wondering, if there is any way, to wake up a thread that is waiting on a condition variable. I.e. something like:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>


std::mutex mux;
std::condition_variable cv;

std::atomic_bool doWait{ true };

void signalHandler(int){
    doWait = false;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    //register signal handler
    //Do some stuff

    {//wait until signal arrived
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mux);
        cv.wait(ul, []{return !doWait; });
    }

    //Do some more stuff
}
```

Which has at least two problems:

1. I believe, I'm not allowed to call `notify_one()` in a signal handler (corrct me if I'm wrong)
2. The signal could arrive just between the check for `doWait` and when the thread goes to sleep, so it would never wake up (obviously, I can't lock the mutex in the signalHander to avoid that).

So far, the only solution I can see is to implement busy waiting on the `doWait` variable (probably sleep for a couple of milliseconds in each iteration), which strikes me as quite inefficient.

Note that even though, my program above has only one thread, I labeled my question with multithreading, because it is about thread control primitives. If there is no solution in standard c++ I'd be willing to accept a solution using Linux/POSIX specific functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that your vendor's standard library uses the `pthread_cond_*` functions to implement C++11 condition variables (libstdc++ and libc++ do this), the `pthread_cond_*` functions are not async-signal-safe so cannot be invoked from a signal handler.

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html:

> It is not safe to use the pthread_cond_signal() function in a signal handler that is invoked asynchronously. Even if it were safe, there would still be a race between the test of the Boolean pthread_cond_wait() that could not be efficiently eliminated.
>
> Mutexes and condition variables are thus not suitable for releasing a waiting thread by signaling from code running in a signal handler.

If you're comfortable using semaphores, `sem_post` is designated async-signal-safe. Otherwise, your options for signal handling are the usual ones: the classic self-pipe, a signal handling thread blocked on `sigwait`/`sigwaitinfo`, or platform-specific facilities (Linux `signalfd`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I feared (although I didn't know the comprehensive list of available Linux/Posix mechanisms). I really hope, We'll get semaphores into the standard one day.